# How Application Request Routing(ARR) will work with IIS Web Services

Tags: iis, nlb, arr

I currently have 2 servers on Which nlb and application pools are running .Since the nlb doesn't recognize, that if an application pool has failed, it sends the request even when an application pool has stopped.

So, I was thinking of Application Request Routing(ARR). But I dont have any knowledge on ARR, since I am very new to this.

My question is - Can the ARR detect whether the Application Pool is running and then balance the load and route the requests accordingly to the servers. Is this possible with ARR or is it possible with NLB also.

Please provide me a link or so, if available.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

ARR has a [health check](http://blogs.iis.net/richma/archive/2010/12/14/application-request-routing-health-check-features.aspx) feature to test if the backend servers are up and running and when configured correctly will only route request to servers it thinks are healthly.

Comment: What about the web service(iis) running has stopped on a particular server, but the server is still up and running , will it still route the request to that server ?